# Error occurs when I update in Eclipse using SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Problem while receiving an update from Eclipse to svn. The error message is '0x00000: Open Project' operation completed with error: 0x000000: Unable connection to 'blah-' project. Please check that SVN meta-information exists and it is supporting the form ...

Except that the operating system has been updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10, nothing has changed, but it is annoying and cumbersome to see such errors every time we update. Of course, there are solutions such as cleaning up or re-connecting, but I want to prevent this problem from occurring fundamentally.

Can you tell me what to look at?
Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Which SVN plug-in do you have (Subversive or Subclipse) in which version? What SVN connector do you use (SVNKit or JavaHL) in which version? If you have JavaHL, try SVNKit instead.

Comment: First of all Thanks for your comment. Yes. I already have been tried SVN connection SVNKit instead of JavaHL,  in my memory, this didn't occur problem but this was too slow When I try to update from SVN. I think have to search for another solution to this issue. I'm using Native JavaHL 1.8.14 and SVNKit 1.8.11 now. If you need the information to solve issue tell me. have a nice day

Comment: It is hard to help without knowing the complete error message, not knowing whether Subversive or Subclipse is used and also not knowing the version of the SVN plug-in. The connectors do not differ in speed (it's all caused by the network). So choose the connector that work for you. Please tell, if you get the same error message in both cases.